# ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000] with my macro

Tags: latex, tex

I am currently trying to compile a LaTex file with a macro being

```
\newcommand{\resumeProjectUrlHeading}[3]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{1.001\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \href{#3}{\underline \small#1} & \textbf{\small #2}\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

And it is being used like this

```
\resumeProjectUrlHeading
          {\textbf{Project\_Name} $|$ \emph{Python}{https://github.com}}{Jan. 2021 -- Present}
```

This leads to the error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@makeother #1->\catcode `#1
                            12\relax
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: ... but urls as macro arguments always screams disaster

Comment: instead have a look at `\urldef` from the url package